# Calling template function with non-type template parameter using class attribute

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, non-type

Suppose you have an `enum class` called `Func`, a class with a `Func` attribute and a `Functions` class containing a function template `compute`:

```
enum class Func
{
    Sin,
    Cos
    // Others...
}

class Functions
{
    public:

        template<Func fn>
        static inline double compute(const std::vector<double>& _args);
}

template<>
inline double compute<Func::Sin>(const std::vector<double>& _args)
{
    return std::sin(std::accumulate(_args.begin(), _args.end(), 0.0));
}


template<>
inline double compute<Func::Cos>(const std::vector<double>& _args)
{
    return std::cos(std::accumulate(_args.begin(), _args.end(), 0.0));
}

// More specialisations...

class Foo
{
    private:

        Func func;
        double result;

    public:

        inline void compute(const std::vector<double>& _args)
        {
            result = Functions::compute<func>(_args);
            // A few other operations follow.
        }
}
```

I would like to call the appropriate specialised template from `Functions` by passing the `func` attribute. However, this doesn't work because `func` is not known at compile time. I get the following error in `clang`:

```
candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'fn'
                                       ^
```

I believe that I can achieve this by making the `compute` method in `Foo` a template as well and specialising for each `Func`:

```
class Foo
{
    private:

        Func func;
        double result;

    public:

        template<Func fn>       
        inline void compute(const std::vector<double>& _args)
        {
            result = Functions::compute<fn>(_args);
            // A few other operations follow.
        }
}

template<>
inline void compute<Func::Sin>()(const std::vector<double>& _args)
{
    result = Functions::compute<Func::Sin>(_args);
}

template<>
inline void compute<Func::Cos>()(const std::vector<double>& _args)
{
    result = Functions::compute<Func::Cos>(_args);
}

// Etc.
```

However, this defeats the purpose because I would like to use the `func` attribute in `Foo`. Also, I would like to avoid the double handling because `Foo::compute()` performs a few more operations, which I would have to copy into each specialisation.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality by using the `func` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template resolution is a fully compile-time mechanism. In this case, you need some way to select at runtime which function is called: function pointers, virtual functions, a switch statement...

Example using function pointers:

```
typedef double (*Func)(const std::vector<double>&);

double Sin(const std::vector<double>& args) {
    return std::sin(args[0]);
}
// etc.

class Foo
{
    private:

        Func func;
        double result;

    public:

        inline void compute(const std::vector<double>& _args)
        {
            result = func(_args);
            // A few other operations follow.
        }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I didn't know you could use `enum`s like that. However, this doesn't allow me to use my `Func` `enum` as an `enum` any more. Is there any way to convert between the two?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, there's no `enum` in my code at all :) Enum classes can only be based on integral types, so you can't have a `enum class : double (*)(const std::vector<double>&) { ... }`. If you absolutely must have an `enum` (but why?), your best bet would be a `switch` statement or a lookup table (e.g. `std::unordered_map<Func, double (*)(const std::vector<double>&)>` or a plain array indexed by the enum cast to `int`) to do the dispatch.

Comment: I realised that there was no enum in your solution shortly after I posted my comment, but I decided not to change it (I don't like rewriting history :)). I was thrown off by the fact that I had never seen function pointers used like this before. Doesn't change the fact that it's a great answer! I do need a way to identify my function with an `enum` (long story), so I have opted for a `switch` statement. It is where I started originally, but now it's a bit cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specialize `Foo::compute`. You may directly use your generic definition:

```
template<Func fn>       
void compute(const std::vector<double>& _args)
{
    result = Functions::compute<fn>(_args);
    // A few other operations follow.
}
```

If you want to turn your runtime member into compile time value, you have to dispatch yourself though. `switch` or array are possible way

```
class Foo
{
private:

    Func func;
    double result;

public:

    void compute(const std::vector<double>& _args)
    {
        switch (func) {
        case Func::Sin: result = Functions::compute<Func::Sin>(_args); break;
        case Func::Cos: result = Functions::compute<Func::Cos>(_args); break;
        // ...
        }
        // A few other operations follow.
    }
};
```

Comment: I did actually have an earlier version using a `switch` statement and non-templated functions, but I thought it was clunky. I wanted to avoid the overhead (as minimal as it is) because these functions are called (hundreds of) thousands of times, so I was after a more direct (inlined) version. I'm happy to know that I was not wildly off track, though. I love the solution suggested by Thomas, but I might have to go back to a `switch` if I can't keep the `Func` `enum` separate from the `Func` function pointer `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve this using templates. Template resolution append and compile time and you want to chose an run-time.
There are a lot of solutions such as the ones proposed but none of them is going to make usage of template.